# android disable / enable tab in tabbedActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, tabwidget

I can not disable a tab in android tabbed activity.
The tabbed activity have 3 tabs and I want to disable the tab in the middle.

I tried the following code in my Fragment but the variable `middleTabView`  is always null!

```
TabLayout tabhostNew = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TabLayout.Tab middleTabView  = tabhostNew.getTabAt(1).getCustomView();
middleTabView.setEnabled(false); //does not work, because middleTabView is null
```

The following code should work, but i am not able to get the variable `tabwidget`.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(your_index).setEnabled(false);
```

Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to call [`getTabWidget()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#getTabWidget()) is implemented in the [`TabHost`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) class and not in [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) (which you are using).

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810306/3459910):

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); // if you are using a view pager

LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0));
for(int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
    tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```