# How to disable click on TabItem inside TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have tabs inside TabLayout and sometimes I need disable some tab, for example tab1 (I don´t need disable all of them, only some of them). Disable means it is not possible tap on it. How can I do that?

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/switchLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/custom" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/custom" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/custom" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
touchableList = tabLayout?.touchables
touchableList?.forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
```

Or you could refer to this:

[How can I disable click on TabLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809538/how-can-i-disable-click-on-tablayout-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for showing me direction. Using touchables doesn´t seem to be good idea, because I must say on which position I want to disable it and disabling with touchables messing with position. Therefore I tried to use setOnTouchListener and it works, thank you.

Comment: glad to know it help